# Should/can we list SuperUser as a migration target when voting to close off-topic questions?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, moderation, migration

[Dori's response to a recent Area51 proposal](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3031/should-this-proposal-be-reopened/3032#3032) indicates that we should do less closing of Photoshop questions and more migrating to SuperUser.  This sounds like a reasonable response to these questions, but there is currently no way to do this without flagging.

It seems like there are enough people here that questions would pass the vote threshhold for migration without mod intervention.  This may also create less Photoshop-question-related questions on Meta as the community would bear the brunt instead of singling out mods for inconsistent closings (which seem to be unavoidable).

This is the dialog I'm thinking of:

[image: close as off-topic dialog]

<strike>*EDIT:*

Per Philip's suggest, this has been posted as a feature-request on [MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109708/can-graphic-design-have-super-user-added-to-its-list-of-targets-for-migration).</strike>

Comment: We'll revisit this once you all have graduated. :)

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to add Superuser, Photography, and UI as migration sites, but typically, they only do that kind of stuff for full fledged sites, not beta sites like this one.

Comment: Thought that might be the case, but hopin' maybe we'll get lucky...

Comment: Can you post some statistics about how many questions are migrated to those sites? (They are available in the moderator tools.)

Comment: The top 3 sites that we send questions to are SU, SO, and UX. I've seen photography as well, but not recently enough to post. So, the 3 sites with a migration path should be the 3 I listed, and a fourth of Photography if available. But none of this really matters until we are out of beta.

Answer (score 0):

The mods here have a slightly different version that adds the ability to search a list of all the SE sites to migrate the question towards.

Comment: Do you think there would be a chance to get it added to the regular tools so we don't have to bug you guys for the common migrations?

Comment: @Farray: Someone would have to make a feature request over at meta.stackexchange.com and then wait and see. So, there's a chance, albeit in competition with the overall din of "The Mecca Meta." I'll try and get to it this weekend or Monday if you don't have the time.

Comment: @Philip A feature request here is fine too; the devs check per-site metas. The real problem is you're still in beta, as [Pearsonartphoto pointed out](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/224/should-can-we-list-superuser-as-a-migration-target-when-voting-to-close-off-topi/225#225). You'd probably need to ask a community coordinator specifically if you're trying to get some sort of exception